# Push Notification is not displaying in Notification Bar Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've just migrated to androidx to implement firebase messaging. 
I've changed everything to androidx and connect my app to firebase. 
At first when I send a notification from firebase console it crashes.
To avoid the crash I put the  `FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);` in my MainActivity.

But still I don't see any notification in the notification list.

In my `Manifest` I put

```
<service android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

For `MyFirebaseMessagingService`

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {
    public static final String TAG = "FirebaseSerive";

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String title = remoteMessage.getData().get("title");
        String body = remoteMessage.getData().get("body");

        Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ss_icon)
            .build();
        NotificationManagerCompat manager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());
        manager.notify(/*notification id*/0, notification);
    }
}
```

After updating my code my emulator is displaying `Failed to post notification on channel “null”`

Thank you for the help in advance.Hope you can help me.

Comment: Is the app in foreground or in background when the message is received? Do you send text or data messages?

Comment: Hi @Robert The app is in Foreground. What is the difference of text or data messages? I only use the Firebase console to send a notificatioin.

Comment: What is the version of Android you tested?

Comment: Hi @lazy Currently I'm testing it on Android 27 
My mind sdk version is 24 and target sdk version is 28

Comment: @natsumiyu To send a notification after android 8.0, you must first create a channel.

Comment: May I know how to create a channel?

Comment: @natsumiyu  It seems that someone has already written the answer below.

Comment: getting the push notification and showing it are two different things. you have to use the channel for this but first, you should confirm that you are getting the required message from the firebase server. do check that first. after that only do the channel declaration. https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels

Comment: @natsumiyu Make sure that you are sending a data message, not a notification message, since onMessageReceived() is coded to receive a data message. FYI, firebase console doesn't support to send data messages. It can be only used to send notification messages. Therefore you might want to use Postman or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this **channel** thing introduced in **OREO**. May be that is causing the issue.

```
    public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    public static final String TAG = "FirebaseSerive";
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "IMP_NOTIFICATIONS";


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        String title = remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
        String body = remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();

        Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(body)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ss_icon);

        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
            notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
            notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
            notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
            notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400});
            assert mNotificationManager != null;
            notification.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }

        mNotificationManager.notify(/*notification id*/0, notification.build());
    }
}
```

Edit:
may be you are getting notification payload instead of data, which you can check by using below code.

```
    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    }
```

[Read more here for example](https://medium.com/cr8resume/notification-in-android-8-0-oreo-implementing-notification-channels-d65b0f81ca50).

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Comment: Should I put it in `onMessageReceived` ?

Comment: This code has 1) unusual formatting, 2) unnecessary code unrelated to the question , 3) contains a dangerous `assert` which can cause the app to crash 4), an unknown `NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID `, 5) uses the mHungarian notation, and lastly 6) is subject to breaking the DRY principle

Comment: formatted code @Zun and added relevant code pieced all together. Thanks for checking out.

Comment: I have received the notification but the title and body is null. Even if I put title and body in firebase console.

Comment: @natsumiyu You must also create a NotificationCompat.Builder to set the text and title.

Comment: @natsumiyu changed the code check now. you were getting notification payload so changed accordingly.